# Add element in an inherited view (Odoo 8)

Tags: xml, view, odoo, odoo-8

I would like to add an element (a button) in an inherited view but we can't add element which are not in the parent view.

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_bill_clients_form">
          <field name="name">bills.clients.form</field>
          <field name="model">res.partner</field>
          <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/> 
          <field name="arch" type="xml">
                  <field name="name" />
                  <!--<button name="account.action_invoice_tree" type="object" string="Generer" class="oe_highlight" />-->
         </field>
</record>
```

If I remove comments from the button I get the error:

```
"Element cannot be located in the parent view"
```

Do you have any idea about how to proceed this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to add new field or any new element on parent view than we need to specify it's position. Means this new field or new element will be shown in view. So in your case try with this:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_bill_clients_form">
      <field name="name">bills.clients.form</field>
      <field name="model">res.partner</field>
      <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/> 
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
          <field name="name" position="after">
              <button name="account.action_invoice_tree" type="object" string="Generer" class="oe_highlight" />
          </field>
     </field>
</record>
```

After *name* field you will see this new button.